# creating ajax controller for all ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some javascript functions like vote_up, vote_down, update_this, update_that etc...

```
application.js

function vote_up
function vote_down
function update_this...
```

All these functions are making ajax requests.

Normally when i create vote_up function in application.js, i create a method in votes_controller. My question is: If i created an AjaxController for all ajax requests, would it be a good architecture?

instead of

```
VotesController

def vote_up

UsersController

def another_ajax
```

this

```
AjaxController

def vote_up
def another_ajax
```

Note: I have too many javascript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do it:

- Keep the public facing actions in their respective controllers since those actions are associated with the resource the controller is (for lack of a better term) controlling. You will also have to make sure that you pull in each resource your actions use manually rather than just having them automatically available.
- Look at the individual actions to see if their is repetitive logic you can refactor out into a module that you mix-in to the controller as needed
- Lastly, think about combining similar functions, such as `vote(userid,resource_type,resource_id,vote_value)` where `vote_value` can be -1,0,1 : -1 => vote down, 1 => vote up, 0/nil => respond with current vote for said resource